# Returning of random values

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I've created random person generator. Divided into functions and class that define the person.
I'm using a Json file for the names. But when I run the code, the name of the person, and the email are diffrent random names, although they are on the same function. I'm guessing it as something to do with wrong return of the function.

```
def Person():
    files = ['global', 'local']
    file = choice(files)
    with open('names/{}.json'.format(file)) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    randomFirst = randint(0, (len(data['first']) - 1))
    randomLast = randint(0, (len(data['last']) - 1))
    firstName = data['first'][randomFirst]
    lastName = data['last'][randomLast]
    email = firstName.lower() + '.' + lastName.lower() + str(suffix) + choice(domain)

    return firstName, lastName, email

user = User(Person()[0], Person()[1], Person()[2])
```

Output:

```
Name:Sarah Gagnon, Email:sofia.sanchez200@yandex.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function multiple times, denoted by `()`, instead you can either just unpack the values that are returned or assign it to a local variable

```
user = User(*Person())
```

```
user = User((p:= Person())[0], p[1], p[2])
```

```
p = Person()
user = User(p[0], p[1], p[2])
```

Comment: Thank you.
I've tried the first option. It gave me the error:
"type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple"
I've changed it into: User(*Person()), and it works just fine.